# How do I merge two vectors probabilistically in R

Tags: r, algorithm, dataframe

I have two vectors X and Y of differing lengths. Assume

```
X = c('a','b','c','d','e')
Y = c('x','y','z')
```

I have a parameter alpha which will be set between the values 0 and 1. I want to merge these two vectors in a probabilistic manner. That is a function that pulls from vector X alpha percent of the time and from Y the remainder of the time. For example if alpha is set at 0.9, then the resultant vector R, could be

```
R = a,x,b,c,d,y,e,z
```

Notice the front portion of the vector has lots more elements from X because alpha is high. Is there a quick way to do this in R? I'm doing this with arrays and queues in Perl which I find is cumbersome. Also, I needn't care if the order is different the next time it is run because its inherently probabilistic.

I need to preserve the order in each vector X & Y. 
Notice the a,b,c,d... and x,y,z are in order.

Comment: Is this sampling *without* replacement? What happens when the X vector is empty? Please clarify.

Comment: This is sampling without replacement. When vector X is empty, only Y is returned (order preserved). If Y is empty, X is returned (order preserved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preserving order of vectors in the output and building off @dickoa's attempt:

```
x <- c('a','b','c','d','e')
y <- c('x','y','z')

prop_x <- 0.9
prop_y <- 1 - prop_x

r <- sample(c(x, y), prob = c(rep(prop_x, length(x)), rep(prop_y, length(y))))

# find indices that are x and substitute x in (guaranteed to be in order)
r[r %in% x] <- x
r[r %in% y] <- y

[1] "a" "x" "y" "b" "c" "d" "e" "z"
```

Comment: @broccoli, are there elements from `X` that are also present in `Y`?

Comment: Careful! The probabilities are incorrect. `prop_x` needs to be `0.9 / length(x)` according to the OPs specification, and `prop_y` has to be adapted too. (This is when sampling *with* replacement is used. Apparently, the question is about sampling *without* replacement -- in this case the problem seems to be misspecified...)

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more please? This seems to work for me quite consistently @krlmlr

Comment: Assume `x` to be of length 1 and `y` of length 1000. How likely is it to select an element of `x` in the first step? @broccoli

Comment: In my case, the probability of choosing an element of x ought to be 90%. I tried a few experiments with sample as follows - sample(10,prob=c(rep(0.15,5),rep(0.05,5))) this works as expected yielding more numbers less than 5 further up the vector. Is your note about normalizing the probabilities?

Comment: @broccoli: Yes, I think so. Perhaps things would be clearer if you told us about the application? I don't see what it means that "the probability of choosing an element of x ought to be 90%". Is it the initial probability, and it decreases as x becomes emptier, or does it always have to be 90 % until x is empty? In the latter case you will have to update sampling probabilities after each step, but also in the former case you need to normalize the probabilities for each set.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sample` to do that

```
X = c('a','b','c','d','e')
Y = c('x','y','z')

set.seed(123)
R <- sample(c(X, Y), prob = c(rep(0.9, length(X)), rep(0.1, length(Y))))
R
[1] "d" "c" "b" "y" "x" "a" "e" "z"
```

---

To get in the same order:

```
set.seed(123)
Z <- c(X,Y)
R <- sample(seq_along(Z), prob=c(rep(0.9, length(X)), rep(0.1, length(Y))))
out <- integer(length(Z))
out[R <= length(X)] <- X
out[R > length(X)] <- Y
```

This'll take care of things even if there are some elements common between `X` an `Y` (not sure if it makes sense in your case though).